# SQL a Eloquent sin resultados

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Buen día, estoy tratando de replicar ésta consulta a marco Eloquent:

```
SELECT legajo, apellido, nombres, dni
FROM employes 
WHERE employes.estado='Activo' and  NOT EXISTS (SELECT null
FROM users
WHERE users.legajo = employes.legajo)
```

pero, estoy tratando con esto sin resultado:

```
    $result=DB::table("employes")->select("legajo", "apellido", "nombres", "dni")
        ->where("employes.estado", "=", "Activo")
        ->whereNotExists(function($query){
            $query->from("users")            
            ->where("users.legajo", "=", "employes.legajo");
        })
        ->get();
```

Comment: Probá cambiando `->where("users.legajo", "=", "employes.legajo")` por `->whereColumn("users.legajo", "=", "employes.legajo")`

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ perfecto, muchas gracias, devuelve exactamente la coleccion que necesito

Comment: Vale. Por favor agrega una respuesta explicando cómo lo resolviste, así le puede servir a otros usuarios. Puedes guiarte por la documentación de laravel donde explican cómo funciona una [where clause](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#where-clauses) y también una [whereColumn clause](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#additional-where-clauses)